# Something wrong with \hfill\vline\hfill?

Tags: formatting

I have been trying to learn Latex, when I found Luke Smith. He has a video about making a [resume](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5-BZ7JmYWk&ab_channel=LukeSmith), but I cannot get the vline to work.
This is isolated code from the video:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{

\begin{minipage}[t]{.15\textwidth}
\hfill\textsc{#1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill\vline\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.80\textwidth}
#2
        
\textit{#3}
        
\footnotesize{#4}
\end{minipage}\\\vspace{.2cm}}

\begin{document}
    
    \entry{2016--2017}
    {Diploma}
    {School of school}
    {More info about the position}
    
\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks in his video
[image]

but mine looks like this
[image]
With the vline all the way to the right.

The two minipages work without the vline, but I want to learn
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something better than proposed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \par\addvspace{1mm}% adjust
  \noindent
  \makebox[.15\textwidth][r]{\textsc{#1}}%
  \hfill\vline\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.80\textwidth}
  #2\par
  \textit{#3}\par
  \footnotesize #4\par
  \end{minipage}\par
  \addvspace{.2cm}%
}

\begin{document}

\entry{2016--2017}
  {Diploma}
  {School of school}
  {More info about the position}

\entry{2016--2017}
  {Diploma}
  {School of school}
  {More info about the position}

\end{document}
```

Using blank lines in the body of the definition is actually OK, but I'd avoid it to make the code more compact. The final `\\` was wrong; I replaced it with `\par` and `\addvspace`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph indentation that begins the line with the first minipage seems to take up so much room that both minipages don't fit on the same line.  You can correct this by either saying `\noindent` just before your `\entry` command, or changing the `.80\textwidth` of the second minipage to `.70\textwidth`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked :).